# Chrome Dev Tools: Local CSS changes unexpectedly persisting after page refresh

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Recently in Chrome Dev Tools when I make local CSS changes, then refresh the page, the CSS changes *stay*. In the past, local CSS changes were not persisted, but the page would refresh to its original state as originally served from the server.

Is there a way to have Chrome Dev Tools behave as it used to, removing the custom CSS changes on page reload?

Comment: You must have mapped a workspace or local overrides in devtools -> Sources panel.

Comment: @wOxxOm Ha!, you're right that did the trick. 
If you post an answer, I'll upvote and mark it as selected. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the dev-tools settings at workspace disable the "save/sync changes to local files".

Then you still have the advantage of the sources combined with the workspace (mapping, debugging, etc.)
but the css changes are not synced immediately.